# If I just use var x to define a variable in the js file running on Node.js,from which scope can it be accessed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let us look at the code that seems confused:

```
var crypto;
try {
    crypto = require('crypto');
} catch (err) {
    console.log('crypto support is disabled!');
}
function hash(message)
{

    console.log(crypto);
    var h=crypto.createHash('sha256');
    h.update(message);
    return h.digest('base64');
}
```

Now,the crypto is undefined when I try to access it from in the function hash,very thanks if anyone can give me a answer.

Comment: Are you getting `crypto support is disabled!` message in the console?

Comment: No,It get the crypto module correctly.

Comment: How are you calling the `hash` function?

Comment: Then it seems highly likely that `crypto` will be undefined. What **exactly** is the error message?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createHash' of undefined
        at hash (I:\twesix\api\nodejs\database\mongodb\index.js:72:17)
        at I:\twesix\api\nodejs\database\mongodb\index.js:14:39
        at Object.o.twesix.user.create     (I:\twesix\api\nodejs\database\mongodb\index.js:9:24)
       at Object.<anonymous>    (I:\twesix\api\nodejs\database\mongodb\index.js:45:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)

Comment: The error occurs inside the function hash but not where function hash is invoked

Answer (score 0):

You can not ensure that when you call the Hash function variable crypto is defined. Use promises in hash invoking.

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
 resolve("Success!");
 // or
 // reject ("Error!");
});

p1.then(function(value) {
   console.log(value); // Success!
}, function(reason) {
   console.log(reason); // Error!
});
```

Comment: If I require the crypto inside the hash function then it works well,is it because requiring a module is an Async action ?